# Unable to cd into a folder

Tags: powershell, cd

I'm try to CD into a folder but I keep getting the below error message.

```
PS A:\> cd "A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1"
cd : Cannot find path 'A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd "A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS A:\> Set-Location "A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1"
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Location "A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

This location does exist I can browse to it without any errors. I can't do CD into any folders if it has []

Comment: Try `cd` ing one directory at a time using `tab` completion. For example: first run `cd "A:\test"` then type `cd fol<tab key>` to have it autocomplete to folder. See if you can drill all the way into the desired directory this way.

Comment: Also, is the directory you are trying to get into a mounted external file system? Maybe a NAS that is formatted with ext4 or something? If so, remember there are some file systems that are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following snippet and it works.

```
cd 'A:\Test\`[Folder`]\Folder1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of PowerShell's cmdlets receive a wildcard pattern via a default parameter named `-Path`. The same applies to [`Set-Location`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7.1) which is what the `cd` alias maps to. Since `[]` is a wildcard pattern, it won't change to the desired folder. You need to use `-LiteralPath` to treat the path as a literal string

> - `-LiteralPath`
>
>   Specifies a path of the location. The value of the LiteralPath parameter is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted as wildcard characters. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell PowerShell not to interpret any characters as escape sequences.
>
> [`Set-Location`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7.1)

Escaping the wildcard characters also work but it'll be much less convenient. So just use

```
cd -LiteralPath "A:\Test\[Folder]\Folder1"
```

In fact `-LiteralPath` can also be used for other cmdlets

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
cd [Folder]
```

do

```
cd ``[Folder``]
```

Comment: Can you verify the second syntax? Seems odd to me..